# Method not found: 'System.Web.Http.Controllers.ServicesContainer

Tags: asp.net-web-api-routing

Am trying to register routes using webAPI in VS2012. At GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes it is throwing the below error. Can someone help me with this?

---

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Method not found: 'System.Web.Http.Controllers.ServicesContainer  
System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.get_Services()'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.    
Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in  the code.

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Web.Http.Controllers.ServicesContainer System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.get_Services()'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request.    
Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the       
 exception stack trace below.
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need the System.Web.Http.Common.dll assembly.